# List admins of a user group?

Tags: user-groups

I was trying to add a user to a user group that I'm currently in.

With

```
pts adduser -user MyFriend -group OneOfMyGroups
```

I got

```
ts: Permission denied ; unable to add user MyFriend to group OneOfMyGroups
```

This makes sense as I may not be the admin of `OneOfMyGroups`.

Now I wish to find out who are. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such thing as a "group admin" in linux.
You only need permissions on a specific file for each action you're trying to make, and that's a general approach on UNIX/Linux.

Most probably you have no rights on `/etc/group`, check it's permissions with `ls -l /etc/group`, and that will tell you who can edit this file.

Usually, it will show root as the only user with write permissions, and that's why on most distros you elevate your privileges with `sudo` and the likes to perform administrative tasks.